# SELECT query INTO temp table with ON DUPLICATE condition

Tags: sql, select

I'm trying to take data from one table(A) to another(B). Table A is throwing errors on the transfer to B because there are records that violate a composite primary key in table B. The Primary Key in B are composed of fields that cannot be modified with the exception of a DATETIME field where the date is important but not the time.

In the confines I'm working under I can only control the select statement from table A and not the insert into table B. I also can't make changes to the data or datatype configuration of either table.

So, with a SELECT statement, how can I grab the data from table A, check it for duplicates in a specific field (an int), and increment the datetime field by one minute in these duplicate instances to allow both records to be inserted into table B.

Comment: Could you have multiple duplicates in A such that you need to add 1 multiple times  A.1, A.2, A.3 all are the same as B.1  so time for A.1+1, A.2+2 and A.3+3 would need to occur.  I could see this possible using a row_number function to add time in the case of multiple duplicates for the same B key. I would suggest creating a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) showing the example you're trying to overcome as well as some expected results.  Also what RDBMS is this? mySQL, SQL server what?  I'm guessing mySQL given on Duplicate condition...

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This will return ONLY records from Table A that do not exist in Table B, so your insert would work.  Of course, without knowing the fields (or anything about your database structure), I can only use mock field names.  If you are still having trouble, edit your question with the needed field names and I'll update my answer.  This is really easy so you should be able to figure it out, even if it requires modifying the following query:

```
SELECT NeededFields
FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
    ON TableA.PrimaryKeyField = TableB.PrimaryKeyField
WHERE TableB.PrimaryKeyField IS NULL
```

When you're done, you should read up on outer joins.  They come in handy!